# Package requirement 'torch===0.4.0+' is not found

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to run the CORnet neural network. For this, I am using Windows, and running the code via Pycharm.
Normally the package manager of Pycharm does not give me any problems but for this it tells me 'Package requirement 'torch===0.4.0+' is not found'.

I have tried installing different versions of torch using pip install.
I have also tried downloading the torch-0.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl file from the pytorch website but then the error message 'torch-0.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform' pops up.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What is that trailing “+” sign in “0.4.0+”. I think this is a typo in your setup.py file (if you use setuptools)

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Not all versions of torch support all version of Python, so if you must use this 3-year-old torch version, you may need to downgrade your Python.

Comment: The `cp37` part in the filename means Python 3.7. So if your Python is a different version, you will need a different wheel/installer.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I think so too, how can I edit this? For set up I normally just click on the install requirements button of pycharm

Comment: @Thomas I am using 3.9 on this machine. I am also running 3.8 on another machine at the CPU only training works there

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE manipulating the requirements in the setup.py does not solve the problem unfortunately. The problem is that I have to run the code from the terminal because of the parser argument structure implemented. But here, when I try and run the code, nothing happens, (no error, but also no output)

Comment: @legomi1 I also noticed a triple equal sign (instead of a double). Can you edit and give us your requirements file or setup.py?